# Change Ribbon tab text

Tags: document-library, ribbon

I need to change the Document Library ribbon tab. I tried to change the text using javascript in master page. But it changes on first load only. When ribbon tab is clicked, text againi changed to default value. Please suggest any idea.

Is it possible to change the content inside upload page? When i click on Add Document link, upload page is loaded. I need to customize the contents.

Comment: Did you change text in CSS file of your master page?

Comment: no i changed using javascript in master page itself.

Comment: This feels like two questions in one! Please split them to get more attention

Comment: ok i will do that.